# How to disable internet connection in WSL2

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

For testing purposes, I'd like to completely cut off any internet connection from within a WSL2 instance.

Could anyone help out?

Comment: Internet only?  Or any lan/wan also?

Comment: Alex, we migrated your post from Stack Overflow because it isn't about *"specific coding, algorithm, or language problems" (i.e. "unique to software development")*.  Please see the [SO WSL tag-wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/windows-subsystem-for-linux/info) for more info.  Since you don't have an account here, note that you can log-in to Super User with the same username/password that you use on Stack Overflow.  That will allow you to respond/comment/vote, etc.  Thanks!

Comment: Disconnect internet or all networking?

Answer (score 1):

There are probably a few ways to do this, but I'd start with the simplest if it meets your use-case:

```
sudo ip link set eth0 down
# optionally
sudo ip link set lo down
```

If you have any other interfaces (e.g. Docker), you can get a list of those in the `UP` state with:

```
ip link show up
```

Note that the network interfaces are shared amongst *all* WSL distributions that you have running, so bringing down a network interface in Ubuntu will also bring it down in, say Debian (or Arch, or Alpine, etc.).

Also note that a `wsl --shutdown` may be needed to reconnect `eth0` with the Hyper-V switch.  Otherwise, you'll at least need to rebuilt your default route.

There may also be ways to brute-force the WSL2 network offline at the Windows level, but I think it would involve deleting the Hyper-V switch for WSL, which I don't recommend.

Comment: That indeed would work! What would be the best way to execute this on startup?

Comment: @Alex How early in the startup?  If you are using Windows 11, you can use `/etc/wsl.conf` and the [`[Boot]` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#boot-settings), but unfortunately WSL is very non-deterministic about its boot order.  Also see [another answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1356147/1165986) of mine on Ask Ubuntu for a way to do this under Windows 10.

Comment: For anyone else coming across this: in order to "rebuild your default route" you can run `ip route add default via [...]`. You can find out which address belongs where it says `[...]` by running `ip route` _before_ running `ip link set eth0 down` and noting down the address from the line that says `default via [...] dev eth0 proto kernel`, where `[...]` denotes the address.